# Получить массив json объектов в resposponse Retrofit

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

Есть метод с помощью которого я получаю список песен с сервера.

```
@GET("/apiV2/MusicSong/GetMusicSongs")
Call<List<Song>> getMusicSongs();
```

Что бы извлечь данные из ответа я делаю так:

```
 Call<List<Song>> musicSongs = RestManager.getApiInterface().getMusicSongs(3,"Step");
        musicSongs.enqueue(new Callback<List<Song>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Song>> call, Response<List<Song>> response) {
                List<Song> body = response.body();
                for (Song song : body) {
                    Log.d(TAG, song.toString());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Song>> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
```

Но я не хочу использовать callback и хочу что бы метод запросы выглядел так:

```
@GET("/apiV2/MusicSong/GetMusicSongs")
List<Song> getMusicSongs();
```

но при вызове метода таким способом я получаю ошибку:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate call
>   adapter for java.util.List.

Можно ли как то получить ответ без использования callback , делаю запрос таким образом:

```
List<Song> getMusicSongs();
```

Comment: Не очень понятно чем это вам мешает? Вам надо синхронно запрос делать?

Comment: Да, верно, я хочу делать запрос синхронно, но при попытке сделать его синхронно я получаю указанную ошибку. Или я просто неправильно делаю запрос?

Comment: Что если как-то так сделать? `List<Song> songs = RestManager.getApiInterface().getMusicSongs(3,"Step").execute();`? Или как-то так (не помню как там конкретно): `List<Song> songs = RestManager.getApiInterface().getMusicSongs(3,"Step").execute().body();`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Вопрос я смотрю минусуют прийдется удалить)). Но Вам - спасибо, не могу протестить, но по-моему это то что нужно.

Comment: Удалять не надо) Протестируйте - если оно - я в ответ кину, вы его примете и +2 репы вернётся)

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, без колбэка, т.е. без `Call` сделать запрос в сеть с помощью ретрофит - нет возможности, и не важно синхронный это запрос или асинхронный.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Спасибо, это работает. Call все равно нужен, но запрос выполняется синхронно судя по исходникам, в любом случае это решило мою проблему. Опубликуйте ответ с .execut‌​e().body();

Comment: @mit Да Вы правы, Call все равно нужен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Синхронно выполнить запрос возможно. Делается так:

> List songs = RestManager.getApiInterface().getMusicSongs(3,"Step").execut‌​e().body();

Но и в этом случае сигнатура метода должна оставаться стандартной, т.е. возвращаться должен `Call`.